# How do I create a regex to exclude 2, 102 and 103

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation

the regex should allow all other digits.
Thanks

Comment: I'd just match all digits and then explicitly check if the matched digit is any of those.  (Also, it's a bit more in the SO spirit to post your attempt.)

Comment: *Re: closure of question.* This question is not vague or ambiguous in any way. Don't close what you don't understand.

Comment: Kaz: It's [incomplete as per the Stack Overflow site FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close). The [guidelines on asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) point out to do some research before and show the progress so far. This cannot be seen in the question above, downvotes/eventual closing are justified.

Comment: I voted to reopen. This question is clear, technical and topical to its tags. The answers are educational about regex.

Answer (score 2):

The same way you use a toothpick to cut down a tree, or parse XML with regular expressions, or write an operating system in COBOL, or do *anything* with Pascal :-)

You don't. You use the right tool for the job, which would be something like (pseudo-code):

```
if val = 2 or val = 102 or val = 103:
    return
# Process other values.
```

Comment: why would you ever answer a "can you do MY job?" question with 196k reputation mate ? i like your point and pascal comment nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

It's far simpler to allow any numbers, then exclude the ones you don't want outside the regex.

```
while (/([0-9]+)/g) {
   next if $1 == 2 || $1 == 102 || $1 == 103;
   say $1;
}
```

But it can be done.

1. Complex pattern,

```
/
   ...
   (?<![0-9])  # Possible to omit in some circumstances.
   (
      (?: 0
      |   [3-9][0-9]*
      |   2[0-9]+
      |   1(?:[1-8][0-9]*)?
      |   10([014-9][0-9]*)?
      |   10[23][0-9]+
      )
   )
   (?![0-9])   # Possible to omit in some circumstances.
   ...
/xg
```

2. Embed Perl code into the pattern

```
/
   ...
   (?<![0-9])  # Possible to omit in some circumstances.
   ([0-9]+)
   (?![0-9])   # Possible to omit in some circumstances.
   (?(?{ $^N == 2 || $^N == 102 || $^N == 103 })(?!))
   ...
/xg
```

3. Negative lookahead

```
/
   ...
   (?<![0-9])  # Possible to omit in some circumstances.
   (?!(?:2|102|103)(?![0-9]))
   ([0-9]+)
   ...
/xg
```

The tricky part is making sure that

- 20 matches
- 102 doesn't get matched as 10

Comment: @user1299558, I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

True regex compilable to an NFA/DFA:

`length 1:`

```
  [0-13-9]
```

`length 2:`

```
  [0-9][0-9]
```

`length 3:`

```
  [02-9][0-9][0-9]

  10[0-14-9]

  1[1-9][0-9]
```

`length 4 or more:`

```
  [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+
```

`combine:`

```
  [0-13-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[02-9][0-9][0-9]|10[0-14-9]|1[1-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+
```

`grep line for validation:`

```
  grep -E '^([0-13-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[02-9][0-9][0-9]|10[0-14-9]|1[1-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, do you mean get one number per line and throw out ones that are "2", etc.?

```
if ($a =~ /^(\s)*(10)?([23])(\s*)$/ || $a =~ /^(\s)*(2)(\s)*$/)
     {
                #bad string!  do whatever
     }
 else
    {
                #good string!
    }
```

This matches

```
2
102
103
```

that is, a line with JUST your "bad" number and maybe some spaces. "111103444", is considered a "good number", so if you mean to filter out your bad numbers try something like

```
$a =~ s/^(?:102|103|2)$//g;
```

which may not technically be a pure regex...

Why did someone say not to use perl for regular expressions???

Comment: I didn't say you shouldn't use Perl for regex, I stated that you shouldn't use regex for this task. That monstrosity of yours is why :-)